# import win32gui error even though i have got pywin32 installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32gui

I have got pywin32 install   using  #pip install pywin32

win32gui is available in lib/site-packages/win32/win32gui, but whenever i try importing win32gui i get

> error: no module named win32gui

I tried the following imports

`import win32gui`

`import win32.win32gui as win32gui`

`from win32.win32gui import win32gui`

`from win32 import win32gui`

nothing works for me .

my python version is 3.9

Comment: Please confirm the `lib/site-packages/` is in your environment variable.

Comment: yes it is available in my env